# Dot matching instead of ? group in Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that matches HTML-like bracket tags of a specific type. This expression should match the tags if they are in HTML comments, too, with group 1 matching the contents between the tags.

To clarify, the expression should match both

`[section]Blah blah blah[/section]`

and

`<!-- [section] -->Blah blah blah<!-- [/section] -->`

Here is what I have so far:

```
"(?:<!--\s*)?\[section](?:\s*-->)?(.*)(?:<!--\s*)?\[/section](?:\s*-->)?"
```

The problem is that group 1 (which is `(.*)`) includes the potential start of a following comment (which is `<!--\s*`). Removing the `?` from after the second `(?:<!--\s*)` gets group 1 to exclude it as it should, but then the expression will not be able to match the tags without the HTML comment syntax.

How do I get group 1 to exclude the second comment start if it is there, while still maintaining the possibility that there won't be a comment start there?

Comment: Does `(?:<!--\s*)?\[section](?:\s*-->)?(.*?)(?:<!--\s*)?\[/section](?:\s*-->)?` accomplish what you're looking to do? (Just added `?` after `.*` so it wouldn't match multiple endings.

Comment: @PiMarillion Post that as an answer and with some confidence and I shall accept and upvote it while singing the song of a thousand tired programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a `?` after the `.*` will make it "lazy" so it won't match any extra ending tags.

```
(?:<!--\s*)?\[section](?:\s*-->)?(.*?)(?:<!--\s*)?\[/section](?:\s*-->)?
```